# How to fix a particular column value when moving a table row up or down by clicking external button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to perform the selected row to move up 'onclick' of "Move Up" button and move down 'onclick' of "Move Down" button but the last column need to be fix its position which means all the other rows can change their position except the last column. In my problem button is not inside the table but is outside the table area.

Please check my code below:

```js
function get_previoussibling(n) {
  x = n.previousSibling;
  while (x.nodeType != 1) {
    x = x.previousSibling;
  }
  return x;
}

function get_nextsibling(n) {
  x = n.nextSibling;
  while (x != null && x.nodeType != 1) {
    x = x.nextSibling;
  }
  return x;
}

function MoveUp() {
  var table,
    row = this.parentNode;

  while (row != null) {
    if (row.nodeName == 'TR') {
      break;
    }
    row = row.parentNode;
  }
  table = row.parentNode;
  table.insertBefore(row, get_previoussibling(row));
}

function MoveDown() {
  var table,
    row = this.parentNode;

  while (row != null) {
    if (row.nodeName == 'TR') {
      break;
    }
    row = row.parentNode;
  }
  table = row.parentNode;
  table.insertBefore(row, get_nextsibling(get_nextsibling(row)));
}
```

```html
<title>Moving Row Up/Down</title>



<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Justine</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Samuel</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Clifa</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnMoveUp" class="myButton" value="Move Up" onClick="MoveUp.call(this);" />
<input type="button" id="btnMoveDown" class="myButton" value="Move Down" onClick="MoveDown.call(this);" />
```

Comment: You have a typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mplungjan for editing the text in awesome way.

Comment: Ok added `</tr><tr>` - the console message is very clear

Comment: Try using elementSibling

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const tb = document.getElementById("tb")
  document.querySelector("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt=e.target;
    if (!tgt.classList.contains("myButton")) return;
    const dir = tgt.id==="btnMoveDown" ? 1 : -1;
    const row = document.querySelector(".highlight");
    const prev = row.previousElementSibling;
    const next = row.nextElementSibling;
    if (dir === 1) {
      if (next && next.nextElementSibling) {
        tb.insertBefore(row,next.nextElementSibling);
      }
      else {
        tb.appendChild(row)
      }
    }
    else if (dir === -1) {
      if (prev) tb.insertBefore(row,prev);
    }
  })
  document.querySelector("tbody").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt=e.target;
    const row = tgt.tagName==="TR" ? tgt : tgt.closest("tr");
    const selected = document.querySelector(".highlight");
    if (selected) selected.classList.remove("highlight")
    row.classList.add("highlight")
  })
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<title>Moving Row Up/Down</title>
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Justine</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Robert</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Samuel</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Clifa</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<nav>
  <input type="button" id="btnMoveUp" class="myButton" value="Move Up" />
  <input type="button" id="btnMoveDown" class="myButton" value="Move Down" />
</nav>
```

Move first 3 columns

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const tb = document.getElementById("tb")
  document.querySelector("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.classList.contains("myButton")) return;
    const dir = tgt.id === "btnMoveDown" ? 1 : -1;
    const row = document.querySelector(".highlight");
    const prev = row.previousElementSibling;
    const next = row.nextElementSibling;
    const rowsToCopyLength = row.cells.length - 1;
    let cells = [...row.children];
    if (dir === 1) {
      if (next) {
        let targetCell = next.lastElementChild;
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsToCopyLength; i++) {
          next.insertBefore(cells[i], targetCell)
        }
        cells = [...next.children];
        targetCell = row.lastElementChild;        
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsToCopyLength; i++) {
          row.insertBefore(cells[i], targetCell)
        }
        row.classList.remove("highlight");
        next.classList.add("highlight");
      }
      
    } else if (dir === -1) {
      if (prev) {
        let targetCell = prev.lastElementChild;
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsToCopyLength; i++) {
          prev.insertBefore(cells[i], targetCell)
        }
        cells = [...prev.children];
        targetCell = row.lastElementChild;        
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsToCopyLength; i++) {
          row.insertBefore(cells[i], targetCell)
        }
        row.classList.remove("highlight");
        prev.classList.add("highlight");
      }
    }
  })
  document.querySelector("tbody").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const row = tgt.tagName === "TR" ? tgt : tgt.closest("tr");
    const selected = document.querySelector(".highlight");
    if (selected) selected.classList.remove("highlight")
    row.classList.add("highlight")
  })
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<title>Moving Row Up/Down</title>
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Justine</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Robert</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Samuel</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Clifa</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<nav>
  <input type="button" id="btnMoveUp" class="myButton" value="Move Up" />
  <input type="button" id="btnMoveDown" class="myButton" value="Move Down" />
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution but the last column should not move. In your solution I have checked that the column is moving. But for the rest thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would the last column not mover?

Comment: See updated code that moves first 3 cells up and down

Comment: Great !!... Wiil check now and will definitely let you know whether it worked or not... Thanks a ton for you support

Comment: "cells = [...prev.children];" - can you please tell me what ... means here?

Comment: It’s the spread operator. It makes the html nodelist into an array since ie does not support forEach on a nodelist